# How to select parent based on the child in lxml?

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

I have this code:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Something else</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <a href="http://exact url">Something</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Something else</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to find the Table but is very hard to target it (the very same code is used like 10 times). But I know what is in the URL. How can I get then the parent table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `t` is the `etree` for this snippet of XML, then the link you're looking for is

```
t.xpath('//a[@href = "http://exact url"]')[0]
```

From there, you can get to the `table` using the `ancestor` axis:

```
t.xpath('//a[@href = "http://exact url"]/ancestor::table')[-1]
```

Comment: larsmans: The last line in your answer will get the outermost `table` of all tables with descendant the wanted `a` element. I think that the OP needs the innermost table.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: you're right, I should have taken the last element of the list. Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: Python. Negative indexes start at the end of the list. *Very* useful feature.

Comment: Yes, agreed. So, actually, arrays represent circular sequences.

Comment: Not exactly. If you index past the end, you get an `IndexError` rather than wraparound.

Answer (score 2):

Filter tables by using []. Note that the attribute is a grandchild `//table[.//@href="blah"]`

Or `//a[@href="blah"]//ancestor::table`

Answer (score 2):

**A pure XPath solution.**

**Use**:

```
(//a[@href = "http://exact url"])[1]/ancestor::table[1]
```

This selects the first ancestor `table` of the first `a` element in the XML document, the string value of whose `href` attribute is the string `"http://exact url"`.

**This provides the correct `table` element even in case when there are nested tables** each of which has the wanted `a` element as descendant. In this case the above XPath expression selects the *innermost* such `table` -- in contrast with the currently accepted answer, that obtains the *outermost* `table` ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

`//a[@href="http://exact url"]/../../..`

You'll need 3 `..`s to reach the table element.

Comment: Ah. Still, not a particularly pretty or general solution.

Comment: Agreed, your solution is more elegant.