# Extract parent tag attributes using text from nested tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to return the information from XML where a particular string of text was found.

Example:

```xml
<xml xmlns:condition="uri:founder.com/data/condition/2.0" xmlns:report="uri:founder.com/data/report/2.0"> 
  <condition:locate name="VAR1">
    <condition:path value="/foo/bar/*'>
            <report:code>12345</report:code>
    </condition:path>
  </condition:locate>
  <condition:locate name="VAR2">
    <condition:path value="/spam/eggs/*">
            <report:code>567891</report:code>
    </condition:path>
  </condition:locate>
```

I am using lxml with python.

```python
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
codes = []
namespaces = {'condition':'uri:founder.com/data/condition/2.0','report':'uri:founder.com/data/report/2.0'}
for items in iter(root.xpath('//condition:*/report:code/text()',namespaces=namespaces)):
        codes.append(items)
sett=set(codes)
print(sett)
```

I am using `set()` to remove duplicates. I can successfully retrieve the code values (12345 and 567891) but I need the parent tags with the condition name and attributes.

I have been playing around with the following, but I need just the final path to the tags and the attributes :

```python
for i in sett:
    for x in root.xpath('//text()[contains(., {})]/parent::*'.format(i)):
        out = tree.getpath(x)
        print out,"\n\n\n"
```

Update: Now I just need to get the attributes for the xpath results.

Comment: If you have some code working, it's always good to provide it. I believe you have a .getparent() you can use, but also .xpath(), which gives you / separated path to the nested element.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471419/how-to-select-parent-based-on-the-child-in-lxml may be helpful. I think you could use ancestor::condition')[-2:], which would give you the last two condition element tags I think. I don't have lxml, but hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks so much @ASmallShellScript! I realized that my first mistake was the variable i was inside single quotes, so I changed up my method: `for x in root.xpath('//text()[contains(., {})]/parent::*'.format(i)):`